# How to: request the url and zip it with response in rxjs?

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, rxjs

I am doing it like this:

```
let urls = [url1, url2, url3];

let urls_ = Observable
      .from(urls);

let ajax = function() { return promise; };

let results_ = urls_
      .flatMap(ajax)
      .zip(
        urls_,
        (response, url) => {
          return {url, response};
        }
      )
```

But the problem with this is that `{response, url}` pairs mismatch, that url1 don't really go with response1. I am facing this use-case too often to not have an operator for this, i.e do something async on an initial Observable, then pass both the initial observable and async result forward.

Is there an operator in RxJS for doing this? Otherwise how can I accomplish 1-1 zipping in my example?

Comment: something like this: http://plnkr.co/edit/kuzbnpGDiyTYRnPvXNQo?p=preview would do the job, unless you wanted to keep the original sequence so process (url1, res1) first then (url2, res2).

Comment: That's how I solved it. I was hoping there would be some operator which already do this, it's a very common use case I've seen in multiple apps. I guess I might be doing something wrong to face this: `source -> flatMap -> zip` pattern. Either way, thanks.

Comment: it is different from what you have -- the zip is inside flatMap and you are therefore guaranteed that urlX will be paired with responseX.

Comment: I understand :) . Code I have in question is the general pattern I am seeing in my apps, for which I am looking for an operator, hoping it would solve my actual problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`flatMap` has an [overload](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/selectmany.md) that will handle it for you, the second argument accepts a method which has the signature

```
function resultSelector(outerValue, innerValue, outerIndex, innerIndex)
```

You use it like so

```
let urls = [url1, url2, url3];

let urls_ = Observable
      .from(urls);

let ajax = function() { return promise; };

let results_ = urls_
      .flatMap(ajax, 
         (url, response) => {
           return {url, response}; 
         })
      )
```

Comment: elegant, did not know about it as well :)

Comment: You are very welcome. Admittedly it's not a terribly publicized overload. Most of the tutorials I've seen don't mention it.